# Наиболее оптимальный запрос к БД из двух возможных

Tags: php, sql

Так вот в БД есть 2 таблицы - users( с данными пользователей) и articles (со статьями этих же пользователей.) При выводе списка статей на экран должно быть выведено: название статьи и имя автора и его логин(чтобы не спупать с другим автором). Вопрос: что оптимальней с точки зрения серверных ресурсов (нагрузка на процессор, объем занимаемой БД) -

1. В таблице articles ввести поля user_login, user_name и соответственно их и выводить (при этом дублируя данные,  находящиеся и в таблице users.
2. В таблице articles указать только поле user_id, и использовать  объединенный запрос, типа:

   SELECT a.content,a.date u.login,u.name FROM articles a JOIN users u ON a.user_id=u.user_id

Comment: Если данный селект будет кэшироваться, то без разницы. Все зависит от вашего желания найти себе геморрой на ровном месте.  

ЗЫ Угадайте за какой вариант я? ;)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, за второй ))

Я про кэш ничего не знаю. Просто выводится список статей с  

    <a href='/id=' >название статьи</a>
Пользователь тыкает на ссылку - и из БД выводится статья.

Comment: Ну, если вы предполагаете миллионы посещений в секунду, то база не справится с такой нагрузкой, вам в любом случае придется обращаться за помощью к memcache.  
У вас же читателей будет гораздо больше чем писателей и в основном информация для всех будет выводиться одна и та же. И только когда выйдет новая статья что-то будет меняться. В этом случае постоянно дергать базу вообще никакого смысла нет.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, где можно быстро и доступно :) ознакомиться с мемкэш? Пока не поздно...

Comment: Например, [отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108274/)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо! Опять учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться.

Comment: Рекомендую почитать про *нормальные формы*, чтобы п.1 даже не рождался в вашей голове. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Если связка `join` по индексированному полю `user_id` - потерю производительности вы даже не почувствуете. Так что 2-й вариант, в котором поля `user_id` в обоих таблицах индексированы.

1-й вариант фтопку - даже не хочу объяснять почему.

Comment: @Barmaley, вот мой второй вопрос как следствие - http://hashcode.ru/questions/259988/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: @Deus вам же там все правильно объяснили. Надо не удалять запись, а каким-то образом помечать как неактивную. Ну как вариант - почистить все поля в таблице `Users`, оставив живой только имя юзера, а хэш пароля, емейл и проч. удалить.

Comment: @Barmaley, хорошо. Так и есть. Спасибо.